# Add horizontal line to chart in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I am using a `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Chart` to plot some x,y scatter data, like this:

```
chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(stringX, doubleY);
```

1. I would like to add to that chart an horizontal line with an average of the form y = constant. **How can I do this? Please, notice that the x axis is a string**
2. Actually, the x axis is the time (hh:mm:ss). I am converting it to string to plot it because if I use the DateTime format for the x axis (XValueType) of the chart it doesn't show the seconds. **Can I correct that to show the seconds so I can plot directly x as DateTime and y as double?**

Comment: You can achieve the same results with a `StripLine`, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524501/custom-x-y-grid-line-in-mschart-control

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For point 2, you can still set the `XValueType` to `DateTime` but with proper format in `LabelStyle`.

```
chart1.Series[SeriesName].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
// Use the required format. I used the below format as example.
chart1.ChartAreas[ChartName].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss";
```

For point 1, add a `StripLine` to the Y-Axis of the chartarea.

```
StripLine stripline = new StripLine();
stripline.Interval = 0;
stripline.IntervalOffset = average value of the y axis; eg:35
stripline.StripWidth = 1;
stripline.BackColor = Color.Blue;
chart1.ChartAreas[ChartAreaName].AxisY.StripLines.Add(stripline);
```

Comment: what is ChartName in chart1.ChartAreas[ChartName].AxisY.StripLines.Add(stripline);

Comment: @Silver, actually it is the ChartAreaName not ChartName... I have corrected the code... thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The default ChartAreaName is named "ChartArea1"

Answer (score 0):

I would add another series with the same X values but a constant Y value that represents the average.

```
double avgY = {average of Y points}
```

and in your loop:

```
chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(stringX, avgY);
```

Comment: Doesn't add a horizontal line it adds a peak to the specified position.